# What to call requirements that are "assumed"/"invisible"/"very obvious"

Tags: requirements, specifications

I'm looking for an umbrella term for all the nitty-gritty requirements that it's helpful to have specified up front but which the client never thinks about in his excitement about the product.

In the client's mind, they think of the headline requirements, the main user stories such as "I need to be able to view the status of all equipment" and "I need to receive automatically any notification equipment failure". But at times the mundane ones are there but the client never mentions them until the result differs from his unspoken expectations: "Well *of course* a user must be able to change his own password" and "*Of course* the user's session must time out after 30 mins"

Any development team can anticipate what's likely to be needed but is there a name for this category of requirements? Obvious/infrastructural/boring/details?

Comment: If it gets to the point of angrily waving contracts in which said "requirements" were never recorded, then you're well within your rights to describe them as "not requirements".  :-)  (I am not a lawyer, btw.)

Comment: Why wouldn't they simply be called "missing requirements". Because that's what they are.

Answer (score 13):

Infrastructure details are called "non-functional" requirements.  It's a weird term describing those requirements that are not visible to the end-user, but are still necessary for the application to function properly.

However,

> The application shall provide a mechanism for allowing the user to change his password

and

> The user session must time out after 30 minutes

are *not* non-functional requirements, and they are *not* obvious.  Always capture such requirements, and put them in your requirements matrix.

Comment: That's the thing, they are requirements and will be subject to tests.

Comment: Non-functional requirements are often *part* of the missing requirements, thus when you refer to the thing described by the OP by "they" in your first sentence, you don't hit it precisely. I am pretty sure you are aware of this.

Comment: @Mike: So test them.

Comment: @DocBrown: I have clarified my answer.

Answer (score 12):

I'd categorize those as "implicit" requirements.  Like "User must be able to log in" implies that there is the notion of a User (with an associated database table/store of some sort), some notion of a password or other credentials, and the requirement to store the user ID or some other token in the session.  This further implied (to me, anyway) that there must be some kind of user maintenance process for adding and removing users, and probably a report of some kind showing user name, first login date, last login date, associated e-mail account and anything else you're keeping track of.

Comment: 'Implicit' is pretty darn good!

Comment: I've always heard them called "implied requirements", but the gist is the same.

Comment: This actually demonstrates the danger in leaving "obvious" requirements to the ether.  The very first implied requirement assumes that the application will have its own user accounts, rather than passing off authentication to a separate system like LDAP or an OAuth provider.  The implication that the application should allow for user management builds off this (possibly incorrect) assumption.

Comment: This is a good word for your examples, but doesn't quite sound like what the OP is describing.  More like the opposite - where "there is the notion of a User" is in the requirements in some form, but "obvious" actions like "the user can change their password" were not, and so completely missed.  "implicit" requirements are `A` where `A implies B` and `B` was requested, not the other way around

Comment: @Izkata When something is 'implicit' that means that that thing is 'implied' by a given, not that it implies a given. This is for the same reason that (for example) the axiom of choice is not implicit in all situations where only a weaker axiom is assumed, like the axiom of countable choice. Your reasoning would have us assume that the axiom of choice _is_ implicit in all situations where only weaker axioms are assumed.

Comment: @AJMansfield Not sure where you're getting that meaning of "implicit" (and I'm not following the axiom of choice part); I'm using the dictionary, which says "Implied or understood though not directly expressed", which is _exactly_ what my example was for.  `A` was implied by the request for `B`; `A` is the implicit requirement.

Comment: @Izkata in your original comment: "'implicit' requirements are `A` where `A implies B` and `B` was requested." What you are stating there is that if any requirement is assumed, any other requirement is implicit if the original explicit requirement would be a consequence of it. The statement "A implies B" means the same as "If A is true, then B must also be true. If A is false, B may be true or false". "A" is called the 'predicate', and "B" the 'consequence'. The statement in your later comment is correct, but the way you phrased it in the original comment is not.

Comment: @AJMansfield Ahh, oops.  I must have just typed it wrong - `A is implied by B` is what kept going through my head.  Sorry!  (I think I wrote it in my answer the right way around, though)

Answer (score 8):

I think that the closest thing that I can think of would be a "derived requirement". These are requirements that are generated by the development team, based on a number of sources such as regulatory agencies, corporate guidelines, and past experiences on similar projects.

However, even after you derive additional requirements from the customer/user requirements, it's important to validate them with the customer/user to ensure that they are correct. After you validate them, you track them just like every other requirement. Note that just because some guideline or experience suggests a requirement doesn't mean that the customer wants it. In fact, it could be contrary to what is expected from the system.

Comment: +1. I have often worked together with devs which were pretty "good" in making wrong assumptions about what the customer might want. So it might be also a good idea to keep some kind of log about potential requirements which have been analysed as not needed, not important or plain wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I'd just go with `assumptions` (or, `unwritten assumptions` if it should be more precise).

`Implicit`, from another answer, doesn't quite work, because what was requested doesn't necessarily rely on them.  For example, `user must be able to change their password` isn't implicit unless another requirement makes reference to a user changing their password with the assumption that it already works.

`Very obvious`, from the question, doesn't really work either.  It could easily be something that's only obvious to someone with appropriate domain knowledge, or works very closely with the product.  Or, to use the password example, it may be that users *shouldn't* be able to change their passwords, and only admins can.

What you're describing are things that the client `assumed` would be done.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this from another site and wanted to add my two cents.

In my view the moment a client/manager starts using phrases like 'it is obvious' or 'it was obvious' the contract between the project owner and the developers breaks down.

When a developer implements something correctly, but misses something that was 'obvious' (but not specified) it will be the developer's fault; when they implement something that was not specified it will be their fault for not following the specification. This is how software development works in companies where the developers are blamed for every failing - usually with a weak manager who is happy to have people to offload the blame onto.

All requirements should be documented, explicitly, even if it seems that the obvious is being stated. That way there is no doubt about what is being built and a clear audit trail to explain why something is not as the client would have hoped.